# clang++ link issue under ubuntu 11.04 with libc++

Tags: linux, clang, linker-errors, libc++, clang++

I compiled libc++ under ubuntu 11.04, made soft links

```
#>ln -sf libc++.so libc++.so.1.0
#>ln -sf libc++.so.1 libc++.so.1.0
```

under /usr/lib, also soft link for stl header files

```
#> ln -sf /my_INSTALL_PATH/libcxx/include/* v1/
```

under /usr/include/c++

When I compiled a small multi-thread hello world example,
the compile returned following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i made mistake in soft link,it should be:

ln -sf libc++.so.1.0 libc++.so 
ln -sf  libc++.so.1.0 libc++.so.1

sorry for bothering